# How to free space after I drop a column of a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

The background is that there is a column `Fn` in a table `DataProcessed` in SQL Server. Plus, the property of `Fn` is `varchar(max), NOT NULL`.

The problem is that I hope to drop `Fn` from `DataProcessed`, and free the space which is occupied by `Fn` in the NDF files of `DataProcessed`.

How can I finish that? Or, is this doable?

Answer (score 3):

You can run a [**shrink**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15) on your database or its individual files, but in general it's not recommended to do because it's a heavy operation and generally wasted efforts because the space will likely be re-used by your database anyway which will result in a **growth operation** which is also not a lightweight operation.

When you drop the column, the space it was previously using on disk will be *recycled* and re-used by your database as it needs more space anyway. It isn't just wasted space just because the OS shows it consumed from the disk. SQL Server manages the space it reserves from the disk internally for the very reason of reducing those heavy **growth operations** I mentioned earlier. So no need to worry about **shrinking**.

You can also find more good information on why [**shrinking** is a wasteful operation here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/), including how it causes index fragmentation. And rebuilding indexes to defrag them will only cause the database to grow again, making the original shrink operation pointless.

Also, last thing to note is that a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column doesn't consume the entire ~2 GB it's capable of maxing out at, for each row, unless you were filling it to the max. It's approximately equal to 1 byte per character you're actually using in it, in general (not counting any additional space saving features going on under the hood like compression). So the space savings you might anticipate by dropping it is potentially less than you think.

Answer (score 0):

First, having `Fn` as `varchar(max)`, does not necessarily mean that this column takes a lot of space
You can get an idea how much space this column takes by running below

```
select avg(len(Fn)) [Avg_Fn] from DataProcessed
```

For varchar, 1 symbol = 1 byte, + 2 bytes for length information, total 3 bytes per row
So you can multiply `total number of rows` * (`Avg_Fn` + 2) / 1024 / 1024, to get the idea how much Megabytes will be actually freed by dropping the column

---

If you still want to delete the column, then you can use below:

Create procedure `SpaceUsedRating` inside your database.
It can be found here: https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools

Before dropping column `Fn`, check how much space table `DataProcessed` consumes
For this you simply run `SpaceUsedRating` procedure

```
exec SpaceUsedRating
```

Find table `DataProcessed` the list, and look at `Table_Total_MB` column

Also remember the `Table_Unused_MB` column value
It is how much space is reserved by the table, but actually is empty

---

Drop the column `Fn` by running

```
alter table DataProcessed drop column Fn
```

Run the SpaceUsedRating again, and see how `Table_Total_MB` and `Table_Unused_MB` changed for `DataProcessed` table

If you see high `Table_Unused_MB`, it means that after deletion of the column, space has not been reclaimed by SQL Server yet. To reclaim it, you may want to wait, or do following:

To speed up space reclaim, you may want to rebuild the table

```
Alter table DataProcessed rebuild
```

Be careful with rebuild as it may be long and blocking operation

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear at what level you want to reclaim space. You need to define this first:

At the disk level?
Then we are talking about shrink, as described by J.D. Don't shrink unless you really really need that disk space! You *might* have to free space inside the db files first (as per below), I'm uncertain if the shrink process does that work for you.

Inside the database files?
Then focus on Aleksey's reply. Doing a rebuild of the table might cut it for you. But another option is DBCC CLEANTABLE. If you read the documentation for this command you see that there's a batchsize you can specify, making it a bit more online-ish than rebuild (unless you are on Enterprise Edition where you can do rebuild with ONLINE = ON). Also rebuild is more resource intensive than DBCC CLEANTABLE.

(Just to make it clear, you can monitor the size of the table using other means than the SpaceUsedRating procedure mentioned by Aleksey. )